# Custom UITableViewCell with UITextfield using Xcode 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitextfield

I am using a custom `UITableViewCell` with a textfield. I want to access each textfield's data when I press on the right navigation bar button (e.g:Done,etc). I am using following code:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return 2;
}

#pragma mark - UITableViewDelegate

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    CustomCell *cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
    if (cell == nil) {

    }
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    cell.valueTextField.delegate = self;
    switch (indexPath.row) {
        case 0:
            cell.itemImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"user.png"];
            cell.valueTextField.placeholder = @"UserName";
            break;
        case 1:
            cell.itemImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"mail.png"];
            cell.valueTextField.placeholder = @"Email";

        default:
            break;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
-(IBAction)rightNavigationButton:(id)sender
{

NSInteger rowNumber = [projectListTable numberOfRowsInSection:0];

    NSIndexPath *indexpath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[projectListTable numberOfRowsInSection:0] inSection:0];

    for(int i = 0; i < rowNumber; i++)
    {
        CustomCell *cell = [projectListTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:rowNumber inSection:0]];
        NSString *str =  cell.valueTextField.text;

//Do here what you want to do with textfield of each cell
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue like this:

```
 -(void)clickOnSend:(id)sender{

    NSInteger dynamicRows = [self.createUserTableView numberOfRowsInSection:0];
    for (int i=0; i<dynamicRows; i++) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0];
        UserProfileCell *cell = (UserProfileCell *)[self.createUserTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        DLog(@"cell textfield string :%@",cell.valueTextField.text);
    }
}
```